# How to finish solving the recurrence relation from fraction $\phi = (24t^2-54t)/(-20t^3+24t^2-9t)$ obtained by generating function method.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I'm trying to solve a recurrence relation using generating function and I reached the following point in the solution:

$$\phi(t)=(24t^2-54t)/(-20t^3+24t^2-9t)$$

How could I continue from here? I know I'm supposed to get 3 constants as a result and then use them with the recurrence relation in order to solve it but I'm stuck on this damned fraction.

Comment: Are you familiar with the method of partial fractions for reducing rational functions?

Comment: I am not. I'm reading up on it now and trying to understand it. I tried some calculators but im having troubles making sense of the results.

Comment: You could start by eliminating the common factor of $t$ in the numerator and denominator.

Comment: What is the original recurrence relation?